# XPath Query for Google Docs ImportXML

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, google-sheets, salesforce

I'm trying to pull a series of notes out of salesforce, I really just need the body of those notes and I'd really rather avoid copying those manually.

I've got the URLs of the notes into a Google Docs spreadsheet and I'm trying to use ImportXML function to pull specific information out, however I can't seem to get the xpath query right.

After some attempts of my own and a fair bit of research (I am a complete beginner so I might jut be searching for the wrong things) I came up with an xpath query like so:

```
//div[@class="pbSubsection"]//td[@class="data2Col"][5]//text
```

This results in a parsing error.

I also found that I can open up the Note in Chrome and in developer tools, find the table and right-click to select Copy XPath, which gives me:

```
//*[@id="ep"]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]
```

Even if I append //text onto the end. Obviously this is not as fool-proof as I require; is there something I'm missing here or some tool I can use to figure out the problem with these queries? I tried XMLQuire without much luck.

Then again, if some kind soul wants to take a look at the page code (hastily altered to remove sensitive information) and tell me specifically what I'm missing, I'll settle for that:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/peo5i47du1vtsmu/test.html

The text I'm trying to pull is:

> teamviewer 12345 
>   Server: Customer Name, ST 
>   Username: administrator 
>   Password: password1

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: On the linked page, `test.html`, what is the value or values you wish to extract?

Comment: Hi, sorry! Edited to add that text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"//div[@class='pbSubsection']//td[@class='data2Col']/text()"
```

yields

```
['Connection Details',
 'teamviewer 12345 \r',
 '\r',
 'Server: Customer Name, ST\r',
 'Username: administrator\r',
 'Password: password1']
```

Comment: @RodrigoM: [This page](http://www.davidsottimano.com/how-to-extract-title-meta-data-using-gdocs-xpath-and-importxml/) seems to indicate that Google XPath syntax must use double quotes around the XPath and single quotes around inner strings. I've edited the post to show what I mean.